# Pass a function with predefined parameter to handleSubmit in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have a redux-form inside a component "MyEditDataForm" and I am passing a function for handling submit to it like this:

```
const myHandleSubmit = ({ firstInputFieldName, secondInputFieldName }) => {
  console.log(firstInputFieldName);
  console.log(secondInputFieldName);
};

const EditDataPage = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <MyEditDataForm
          onSubmit={myHandleSubmit}
        />
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

**Console output: "john", "doe"**

So far so good... Now I would like to add a parameter to myHandleSubmit, which I want to pass to myHandleSubmit. Like this:

```
const myHandleSubmit = ({ firstInputFieldName, secondInputFieldName, anotherParameter }) => {
  console.log(firstInputFieldName);
  console.log(secondInputFieldName);
  console.log(anotherParameter);
};

const EditDataPage = () => {
  const aNewParameter = "some info";

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <MyEditDataForm
          onSubmit={myHandleSubmit({ anotherParameter: aNewParameter })}
        />
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

**Output before clicking the submit button: undefined, undefined, "some info"**

**After clicking the button: "Error: You must either pass handleSubmit() an onSubmit function or pass onSubmit as a prop"**

How is it possible to pass aNewParameter to myHandleSubmit, without destroying the form submit functionality? I have tried to do this with bind():

```
<MyEditDataForm
  onSubmit={myHandleSubmit.bind({ anotherParameter: aNewParameter })}
/>
```

**Output: "john", "doe", undefined**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need this:

```
const myHandleSubmit = ({ firstInputFieldName, secondInputFieldName, anotherParameter }) => {
  console.log(firstInputFieldName);
  console.log(secondInputFieldName);
  console.log(anotherParameter);
};

const EditDataPage = () => {
  const aNewParameter = "some info";

  return (
    <Container>
      <Row>
        <MyEditDataForm
          onSubmit={(fields) => myHandleSubmit({ ...fields, anotherParameter: aNewParameter })}
        />
      </Row>
    </Container>
  );
};
```